# Speeding up venus with rocks from mercury

Tags: terraforming, time

I’ve decided that in terraforming venus, the time taken to speed up its rotation by venting the atmosphere is just too much. So, I’ve returned to the idea of bombarding the planet *with* something rather than venting it *away*; namely, rocks from mercury.

A mass driver is constructed in Mercury’s equator. This driver rests on a track encircling the planet’s equator, which keeps it in the same place relative to the planet’s 176-day rotation. Every time it aligns with Venus, the mass driver launches one-ton payloads of iron-rich rock, which intersect and collide with venus, increasing its rotation by a fraction.
The best part, is that the iron released on impact can later be used in the conversion of the atmosphere to water and carbon, but that’s another story…

Assuming a terawatt-scale amount of energy (handily provided by an array of solar power satellites) how fast can I theoretically fire this mass driver, how many payloads could I therefore convey in each brief launch window, and how long will increasing Venus’ rotation to 24 hours therefore take?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with " Every time it aligns with Venus, the mass driver launches"?

Comment: Mercury and Venus regularly align with each other, (i think every 88 days) and during this time the distance between the two bodies is at its smallest. It’s logical to fire the mass driver at this time, since then the payloads have to travel only the shortest possible distance from mercury to Venus.

Comment: Do you take into account the effects you produce on Mercury? The energy / force you apply on Venus is pretty much the same with the energy / force applied on Mercury (but opposite directions).

Comment: @user98816 No, it is not logical to fire the mass driver at that time. You are shooting trough space. There is nothing there. It literally doesn't matter how far you are shooting at, just that you hit your targets in the end. It would be extremely wasteful to have a mass driver sitting idly for 99% of the time. Not that terraforming Venus is a good way to go. Space habitats>suboptimal planets/moons. We kinda need that 1g gravity. Day length is the least important thing you look for in your potential colony world. And lastly, even shooting whole Mercury probably wouldn't be enough for your plan

Comment: Why does it matter how far they have to travel? It's not like they'll go bad in transit. And it's about the highest energy requirement trajectory...if you can hit Venus at that point, you can hit it at any relative phase.

Comment: This is your sixth "how to speed up Venus' rotation?" question. Why is this not inherently a duplicate of the previous five questions? What haven't you learned from those that you need answered by this? Don't you realize yet that there is no scientifically plausible yet fast way to significantly change the rotation of a planet? Why not do something implausible but cool like coil indestructible cord around Venus and extend it to a net to catch Mercury, robbing M of orbital speed to increase V's rotational speed? Or run an indestructible rod through Venus' core and use opposing Bussard Ramjets?

Comment: Even if you can pump enough energy into Venus to speed up its rotation to that extent, which you can’t, you’ll also melt its crust and it will take millions of years to cool down again. You’ll be repeating the Late Heavy Bombardment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that such an arrangement would be so tiny that it would be like trying to move an elephant by flicking grains of pollen at it. It would be swamped by all sorts of other minor astronomical effects. So the answer is for all practical purposes it would take just about forever.

Comment: That does it; to heck with venus, I’m sticking with mars.

Comment: Pollen against mountains.

Comment: A terawatt isn't much as far as a planet is concerned.

Comment: True. It's easy to get lost in the orders of magnitude. Astronomical scale objects and events need to be calculated. Human gut reaction is simply inappropriate. Concepts like x10 x1000, very big indeed just fail. 10-20 orders of magnitude are incomprehensible to gut reaction.

Answer (score 6):

A frame challenge:

Why do you assume that the rotation rate of Venus needs to be changed to make it habitable?

The aim of terraforming a planet is to turn it into a "habitable planet for Man".  In *Habitable Planets for Man* (1964) Stephen H. Dole discussed the properties of a planet habitable for humans.

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

On page 58 Dole wrote that:

> From the standpoint of human habituation there are two limits related to rotation rate. for slow rotation rates a limit would be reached when daytime temperatures became excessively high in the low latitudes below a critical latitude and when nighttime temperatures became excessively low poleward from that same latitude, or when the light-darkness cycle becomes too slow for plants to live through the long hot days and long cold nights.

On page 60 Dole guess that the longest possible day for a human habitable planet might be 96 hours or 4 Earth days long.

Dole then goes on to discuss the special case of a tidally locked planet with a rotation rate equal to its orbital period, so one side always faces the star and one side always faces away from the star in eternal night.   Dole decided that all the water and maybe atmosphere would probably freeze out on the dark side, leaving the planet waterless and maybe airless.

> Astronomers for many years ruled out red dwarfs as potential abodes for life. Their small size (from 0.08 to 0.45 solar masses) means that their nuclear reactions proceed exceptionally slowly, and they emit very little light (from 3% of that produced by the Sun to as little as 0.01%). Any planet in orbit around a red dwarf would have to huddle very close to its parent star to attain Earth-like surface temperatures; from 0.3 AU (just inside the orbit of Mercury) for a star like Lacaille 8760, to as little as 0.032 AU for a star like Proxima Centauri[84] (such a world would have a year lasting just 6.3 days). At those distances, the star's gravity would cause tidal locking. One side of the planet would eternally face the star, while the other would always face away from it. The only ways in which potential life could avoid either an inferno or a deep freeze would be if the planet had an atmosphere thick enough to transfer the star's heat from the day side to the night side, or if there was a gas giant in the habitable zone, with a habitable moon, which would be locked to the planet instead of the star, allowing a more even distribution of radiation over the planet. It was long assumed that such a thick atmosphere would prevent sunlight from reaching the surface in the first place, preventing photosynthesis.
>
> This pessimism has been tempered by research. Studies by Robert Haberle and Manoj Joshi of NASA's Ames Research Center in California have shown that a planet's atmosphere (assuming it included greenhouse gases CO2 and H2O) need only be 100 millibars (0.10 atm), for the star's heat to be effectively carried to the night side.[85] This is well within the levels required for photosynthesis, though water would still remain frozen on the dark side in some of their models. Martin Heath of Greenwich Community College, has shown that seawater, too, could be effectively circulated without freezing solid if the ocean basins were deep enough to allow free flow beneath the night side's ice cap. Further research—including a consideration of the amount of photosynthetically active radiation—suggested that tidally locked planets in red dwarf systems might at least be habitable for higher plants.[86]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_habitability#Suitable_star_systems

So if a tidally locked planet with eternal day on one side and eternal night on the other side might possibly have suitable temperatures for life if it has sufficient atmospheric and water circulation to equalize the temperatures between hemispheres, a planet with very long days and nights but less than eternal ones might also be able to have suitable temperatures for life.

If humans terraformed Venus they might possibly have to help the heat diffusion around the planet by building giant pipes and pumps to pump water between the hot and the cold sides of the planet.  That would be a vast project, but almost infinitely smaller than trying to change the rotation rate of Venus.

And the might have to build their cities with super powerful heating and air conditioning systems to star warm in the coldest period of the night and cool in the hottest period of the day.  But that would be almost infinitely less vast a project than trying to change the rotation rate of Venus.

The solar of day of Venus is 116.75 Earth days.

> An annual plant is a plant that completes its life cycle, from germination to the production of seeds, within one growing season, and then dies. The length of growing seasons and period in which they take place vary according to geographical location, and may not correspond to the four traditional seasonal divisions of the year.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_plant

The growing season for annual plants on Venus might be one quarter to one half of the solar day of Venus, or about 29.1875 to 58.375 Earth days.

> One seed-to-seed life cycle for an annual plant can occur in as little as a month in some species, though most last several months.

So some Earth annual plants might flourish in the long days on Venus, though many others might have to be genetically engineered to do so.

> A perennial plant or simply perennial is a plant that lives more than two years.[1](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf) The term (per- + -ennial, "through the years") is often used to differentiate a plant from shorter-lived annuals and biennials. The term is also widely used to distinguish plants with little or no woody growth (secondary growth in girth) from trees and shrubs, which are also technically perennials.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_habitability#Suitable_star_systems)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perennial_plant

In temperate climate zones, many perennial plants shed their leaves and go domant during the winter months. And maybe they could react to the 58.375 day long nights on Venus like they were short winter season.

So I don't see any reason why the rotation rate of Venus would need to be changed to terraform it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is not a great direction to pursue - for both the pollen vs elephant problem, as well as the fact that Mercury itself will be severely affected by this.

So let's assume that this mass driver accelerates half of the projectiles in the opposite direction to maintain position/Mercury's angular momentum. I'll try to give more context to the pollen vs elephant issue, in the spirit of actually answering the question as asked.

Venus's moment of inertia is around 6.005e37 kg m^2/s^2. Its angular velocity is 2.99e-7 rad/s, and an Earth length day (because why not, when this is such a large project anyway) would mean 7.27e-5 rad/s, basically 243 times larger. Say we accelerate a single 1-ton projectile such that it is on track to strike the equator of Venus at 10km/s almost tangentially relative to Venus, in the direction it currently rotates in. Maybe there's a mountain there that can easily take the full force of the impact of this projectile.

(I'm skipping the orbital rendezvous calculations, as well as the orbit+spin inclination issues here because as you'll see, it's really not worth it).

This will be an inelastic collision, so the linear momentum change will be the full 10km/s. The angular momentum of the projectile w.r.t Venus is (1e7) * 6051000 = 6.05e13 kg * m^2/s. Venus's current spin-angular momentum is (moment of inertia * angular velocity) 1.797e31 kg * m^2/s. You'll have to fire 3.36e18 projectiles to halve its day-length, and then 242 times that to shorten it to Earth levels. At one projectile per second, you'll need 6+ trillion years to achieve this.